# Can't change the TimeZone into GMT/UTC+7

Tags: android, timezone

I have data from my server that return

```
 "createdAt": "2019-01-21T09:55:01.546Z"
```

I've already convert that string into `Date`
so now my date is show up like this:

```
"Sunday, 01-12-2019 09.55 am"
```

my problem is i want the time is offset +7 or `UTC+7`

i have already done this:

```
String dateData = response.body().getCreatedAt();

            SimpleDateFormat inputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
            SimpleDateFormat outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault());

            Date date = null;
            try{
                 date = inputDate.parse(dateData);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            inputDate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            outputDate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+7"));

            mPosted.setText(outputDate.format(date));
```

but the result is still the same. And the weird is when i change `outputDate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));` the time result is change to 02.55 am.

How can i change it to +7? so the ***time should be 4.55 pm***

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Better than an offset, as `+07:00`, use a real time zone such as Asia/Krasnoyarsk or Indian/Christmas. It conveys the *why* much more naturally. Asia/Jakarta may be right for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this

```
try {
                    SimpleDateFormat ip_format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);
                    ip_format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                    SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
                    outFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+07:00"));

                    Date date = null;
                    date = ip_format.parse(dateData);
                    System.out.println("date" + date.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Thanks bro it's worked, outputDate should inside the try catch block